# Access segments in hooks

Tags: segments, hook

Is it possible to access segment or page information in the hooks?

Each hook has different parameters so I can't rely on those to get segment information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into "[URI Class](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/uri.html)"